# SQL NVARCHAR Variable String Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables

I have the following SQL

```
DECLARE @ColIdx INT;
DECLARE @FieldPrefix VARCHAR(50) = N'DX';
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @MaxColumnCount = 8;

WHILE @ColIdx < @MaxColumnCount 
BEGIN
  SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
     COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeaders + N', 
          ['  + @FieldPrefix + CAST(@ColIdx AS VARCHAR) + N'] AS NVARCHAR(100)',
         N'['  + @FieldPrefix + CAST(@ColIdx AS VARCHAR) + N'] AS NVARCHAR(100)') 
  SET @ColIdx += 1
END;

PRINT @@PivotColumnHeaders;
```

I expect the output to be

```
[DX1] AS NVARCHAR(100), [DX2] AS NVARCHAR(100), ..., [DX8] AS NVARCHAR(100)
```

and this is part of a larger SP that is going to insert these columns into a database using dynamic SQL. Granted I have not used SQL for ages, but this is basic and I have no idea why `@PivotColumnHeader` is ending up blank, or indeed why `PRINT` is not working (probably because the variable is blank! - but why?) - I have attempted the normally sound

```
RAISERROR (@PivotColumnHeaders, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

in place of `PRINT` but this is also returning nothing. **What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd try changing the cast of `@ColIdx` to a specific `varchar` value (e.g. `varchar(200)` or whatever would be reasonable), it's probably getting truncated and NULLing out the final value of `@PivotColumnHeaders`.

Comment: Okay, I get that this was a stupid mistake. I will take this. I has been a long week and it's only Tuesday! Thanks everyone for your time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing `@ColIdx`:

```
DECLARE @ColIdx INT;
DECLARE @FieldPrefix VARCHAR(50) = N'DX';
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @MaxColumnCount = 8, @ColIdx = 1;
```

By default the value will be `NULL`, and thus `@ColIdx < @MaxColumnCount` will be `NULL`, so the `WHILE` loop will never execute.

Answer (score 1):

D Stanley has already given the correct answer about @ColIdx, not being assigned a value, thus never entering the loop. I just wanted to point out an alternative to using a loop to generate this column list:

```
DECLARE @FieldPrefix VARCHAR(50) = N'DX';
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @MaxColumnCount INT = 8;

SELECT  @PivotColumnHeaders += ', ' + QUOTENAME(@FieldPrefix + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR)) + N' AS NVARCHAR(100)'
FROM    Master..spt_values
WHERE   Type = 'P'
AND     Number BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxColumnCount;


PRINT STUFF(@PivotColumnHeaders, 1, 1, '');
```

I don't think a simple loop like you have done will ever be consequential to performance, but I just think it is best to avoid loops in SQL where possible, this way it is the last thing that springs to mind whenever we need to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are printing wrong varieble?

You have

```
PRINT @@PivotColumnHeaders;
```

And I think you want

```
PRINT @PivotColumnHeaders;
```

(just single "@")

Comment: Scratch. See @DStanley answer. I think he nailed it.